# how to get number of days between two different dates from different tables in sql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, datediff

I need to estimate number of days between 2 different dates from different table.
I have tried to use `datediff` function, but it did not work.

Here was the query i tried:

```
select 
   t1."group",
   datediff(t2.start_date, t1.event_date),
   count(distinct t1.employee_id)
from t1 join t2 on t1.project_id = t2.id
where true
  and t1.cummulative_manhour > 0
  and t1.company_id in ('a', 'b')
  and t1.event_date = '2021-05-17'
  and t1.project_id = '2900'
group by 
  t1."group",
  t2.start_date,
  t1.event_date
```

The error message said:

```
SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function datediff(date, date) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 29
```

The database I use is postgresql.

How should I write my query in order to get the expected number of days?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you think Postgres has a `datediff()` function? Nothing [in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html) would suggest this.

Answer (score 2):

As the error message suggests, Postgres does not support `datediff()`.  Instead, it just uses `-`:

```
(t2.start_date - t1.event_date),
```